# Solr - EDisMax pf/pf/pf3 Fields Vs ShingleFilterFactory

Tags: solr

Is there any benefit in using the `ShingleFilterFactory` **with** the `EDisMax pf/pf2/pf3` fields? For example, if I have an untokenized index (via `KeywordTokenizerFactory`) with the following values:

```
1. "jeans" 
2. "skinny jeans" 
3. "red blazer"
```

And I query for `"red skinny jeans"`, I would like to match only `"jeans"` and `"skinny jeans"`. With `EDisMax`, using the pf fields should implicitly generate shingles, so is there any benefit in plugging in the `ShingleFilterFactory` as well?

Thanks

Comment: Didn't I provide an suggestion for this yesterday? Are you just deleting and re-adding the question without taking time to respond or try the suggestions? (and no, pf doesn't generate shingles as far as I know - they just use the position data for the tokens being matched)

Comment: @MatsLindh no, my other question does not make reference to shingles, only to the searching for sub-strings. This question relates to how the ShingleFilterFactory (i.e. generating query shingles) and EDisMax (i.e. ALSO generating shingles) interact. Thanks